# How to implement In App Purcharse in ionic 2?

Tags: android, ionic2, google-play, in-app-purchase, payment

I have small issue need some explains or example to implement in app purchase in ionic 2

So, After install the plugin of this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase/

I'm trying to run this code but need help to find the Prod ID of payment for google play... I searched a lot for this point but no good results :(

```
this.iap.buy('prod1').then((data)=> {
   console.log(data);
   // {
   //   transactionId: ...
   //   receipt: ...
   //   signature: ...
   // }
}).catch((err)=> {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: ProductID is normally the one you yourself setup inside google play / apple store interface. Check google plays documentation or guides re this

Comment: after search i found the ID... thanks for ur hint